# How can I efficiently find an entry by title in an atom feed?

Tags: performance, search, title, feed, atom-feed

I want to find an entry given its title, but I don't want to traverse the feed and download the content (possible huge) of each entry until I find the one I'm looking for. In my case, titles are unique across the whole feed, and I'm using Atom Hopper.

Is it possible to get a chunk of entries from the feed without their content, or should I maybe add the title as a category to each entry and use the search parameter?

Comment: that depends on the feed the server is providing... what's the url?

Comment: URL is not public. We are controlling both server and Client for the time being. Atom Hopper defines a title for each entry, and I wonder if an entry with a given title can be found without having to download the entire entries while traversing the feed, and without adding one new category for each entry and search for that with the HTTP parameter "search".

Comment: I see now that I have to use JDBC Data Adapter to do this With Atom Hopper. Does anyone have any experience with category searches using that adapter?